Facing issue while importing MDTabs in KIvyMD[Python]
So I was just coding a calculator app in python using kivy and kivymd, and while using this 'tabs' feature I
got stuck at this issue which I'm unable to fix from very long, below is the code and the error string;
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.tab import MDTabsBase
from kivymd.uix.boxlayout import MDBoxLayout
from kivymd.uix.label import MDLabel
from kivymd.uix.appbar import MDTopAppBar
from kivy.metrics import dp

KV = '''
MDScreen:
    MDBoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'

        MDTopAppBar:
            title: "Calculator App"
            right_action_items: [["theme-light-dark", lambda x: app.toggle_theme()]]

        MDTabs:
            id: tabs
            allow_stretch: True
            pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .5}

            MDTabsItem:
                text: "Calculator"
                icon: "calculator"

                MDBoxLayout:
                    orientation: 'vertical'
                    padding: dp(10)

                    MDLabel:
                        text: "Basic Calculator UI"
                        halign: 'center'

                    # Add your calculator UI components here

            MDTabsItem:
                text: "Converters"
                icon: "ruler"

                MDBoxLayout:
                    orientation: 'vertical'
                    padding: dp(10)

                    MDLabel:
                        text: "Converters UI"
                        halign: 'center'

                    # Add your converters UI components here
'''

class CalculatorApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(KV)

    def toggle_theme(self):
        if self.theme_cls.theme_style == "Light":
            self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Dark"
        else:
            self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Light"

CalculatorApp().run()

**ERROR: **
from kivymd.uix.tab import MDTabs  # Correct import
ImportError: cannot import name 'MDTabs' from 'kivymd.uix.tab' (C:\Python 3.9\lib\site-packages\kivymd\uix\tab_init_.py)
I tried to fix the import by referring to the kivymd 2.0.0. documentation for tabs but nothing really worked

I think the solution is printed in the error message:
from kivymd.uix.tab import MDTabs # Correct import

Place it instead of your code:
from kivymd.uix.tab import MDTabsBase

